# SQLiteDatabase Error, unhelpful Log

Tags: android, android-sqlite, illegalstateexception

I released an update of my app and am getting a ton of errors from users and I can't recreate it or pin-point the problem.

Two errors I'm getting:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase`

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open`

The error is happening somewhere in the following code:

```
public DBUserC getUser(int _id){
        synchronized (DBAdapter.LOCK){
            M.openDB(context);
            Cursor cursor = M.database.query(DBUserHelper.TABLE_USERS,
                    VUser.allColumns, DBUserHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = '"+_id+"'", null, null, null, null);
            DBUserC user;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                user = cursorToInfo(cursor);
            } else{
                user = newUser();
            }
            cursor.close();
            M.closeDB();
            return user;
        }
        }
```

In this version, there is a database upgrade, in which I perform three queries via `db.execSql`. It is not in a separate thread.

On every call to the database (except in the `onUpgrade`), I synchronize, then open it, run my code, then close it. I was having no problems until this upgrade and can't find the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** To open my databas, I do:

```
if (helper==null)
    helper = new DBAdapter(context);
if (database==null){
     database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
} else if (!database.isOpen())
     database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

and to close:

```
helper.close();
helper = null;
database = null;
```

Example method for getting info:

```
    public DBUserC getUser(int _id){
        synchronized (DBAdapter.LOCK){
            openDB(context);//this is the open code above
            Cursor cursor = M.database.query(DBUserHelper.TABLE_USERS,
                    VUser.allColumns, DBUserHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = '"+_id+"'", null, null, null, null);
            DBUserC user;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                user = cursorToInfo(cursor);//does not contain DB operations
            } else{
                user = newUser(); ////does not contain Database operations
            }
            cursor.close();
            closeDB();//This is the close code above
            return user;
        }
    }
```

**AHost.onCreate**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        M.initializeDB(context); //synchronized call to the openDB code I posted above
        M.openDataDB(context); //opens a different database by a different file name. This DB is not an issue

        //irrelevant ui setup
        int _id = pref.getInt(P.eLastUser, VUser.ID_NEW);//row id of user

        M.requeryUser();//synchronized, access database
        M.switchUser(_id);//synchronized, access database

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear ! are you mean for example use : `<hr />` tag ?

Comment: can you post contents of AHost onCreate()?

Comment: I posted all relevant `onCreate` code. I can post M.requeryUser() and M.switchUser() if need be, but that would get fairly lengthy

Comment: Can you point at what line you are getting the error?

Comment: @VikramV, unfoturnately, I cannot. I can't recreate the issue, and the stacktrace from Google Play doesn't give me line numbers.

Comment: @Jakar: Issue solved then as your are not able to recreate it?

Comment: @VikramV, also unfortunately not. In a matter of 1 hour, I have received about 150 reports of the problem via Google Play for a new version I released. Most errors that I cannot recreate I get a maximum of 2-3 reports per day.

Comment: M.requeryUser and M.switchUser use DBAdapter.LOCK as a lock obj?

Comment: my program occurred this exception.it cause by this.in thread a i open db,update the data,and close db.in thread b i open db,query the data,and close db.what i solved is put all data operation in the same thread a.

Comment: @venciallee, Each of those call a couple different methods within them (depending on whether certain values are `null`). Those methods use `DBAdapter.LOCK` as a lock object as do all of my methods that call the database.

Comment: @VikramV, I didn't get the line, but I was able to find the block of code that's throwing the exception. It's toward the top of this question.

Comment: where are you performing the three db.execSql queries ? in onCreate or on upgrade ? can you put its code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not recreate issue because in testing, I was upgrading from DB version 3 to version 4. Many of my users were upgrading from version 2 to version 4. Some of the code for upgrading from 2 to 3 was method-based. I ended up changing some of those methods for version 4, which broke the version 3 upgrade. I then was getting a caught exception from a cursorToObject() method I had, which caused the database.close to be skipped and then I got the sqlite exception

Comment: Shameless plug: I have faced similar problems in the past and my conclusion is that if you want to have independent migrations, i.e. you want to ensure that adding new migration won't break migrations from earlier versions, you have to keep the old db schema definitions. I wrote a library to make this easier and reduce boilerplate: https://github.com/futuresimple/android-schema-utils. I hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue in one of my app, and how i solved that issue is through removing the cursor.close(). Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously we need to see the on-upgrade method seems to be the root cause of your issue.  I use the [Adams Upgrade method](http://blog.adamsbros.org/2012/02/28/upgrade-android-sqlite-database/) I named it for the blog I found it oun.

note:  Each upgrade is done in the upgradeTo <= newVersion loop.  Maybe someday I'll put a progress bar on this loop.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;
    while (upgradeTo <= newVersion) {
        switch (upgradeTo) {
        // update old resrawid's to constants
        // this was caused when I saved R values in the database
        // and then later realized they would change.
        // the old resrawid is changed to a constant.
        case 42:
            ContentValues values;
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            // used for debugging so I can see the value of the update.
            int res;
            int rs;
            rs = 2130968576;
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(
                    KEY_RESRAWID,
                    com.gosylvester.bestrides.ImageTextListViewActivity.SAMPLE_DRAGON);
            res = db.update(TABLE_RIDES, values, KEY_RESRAWID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(rs) });

            rs = 2130968577;
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(
                    KEY_RESRAWID,
                    com.gosylvester.bestrides.ImageTextListViewActivity.SAMPLE_M119);
            res = db.update(TABLE_RIDES, values, KEY_RESRAWID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(rs) });

            rs = 2130968578;
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(
                    KEY_RESRAWID,
                    com.gosylvester.bestrides.ImageTextListViewActivity.SAMPLE_MEDINA);
            res = db.update(TABLE_RIDES, values, KEY_RESRAWID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(rs) });
            break;
        case 43:
            // new column added for last_viewed.
            db.execSQL(VERSION_43_ALTER);
            break;

        case 44:
            // new index on KEY_DATE_UPDATE DESC
            db.execSQL(VERSION_44_CREATE_INDEX);
        }
        upgradeTo++;
    }
}
```

Good Luck
Danny117

Comment: I already solved the problem myself (see my answer), but I do appreciate the effort and information.