# OnUpgrade Android SQLite Database from Assets Folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite, assets

I currently have a database that I am using within my Assets folder. I am having issues upgrading it though. Whenever I up the `DATABASE_VERSION` number it will only update certain times. And when it does upgrade, it crashes at start and I have to reopen the app.

Here is my createDatabase()

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
boolean dbExist = checkdatabase();
if (dbExist) {
    Log.v("DB Exists", "db exists");
    // By calling this method here onUpgrade will be called on a
    // writeable database, but only if the version number has been
    // bumped
    this.getWritableDatabase();
}
dbExist = checkdatabase();
if (!dbExist) {
    // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
    // the default system path of your application so we are gonna be
    // able to overwrite that database with our database.
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        copyDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
    }
}
}
```

onUpgrade()

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion){
        Log.v("Database Upgrade", "Database version is higher than previous.");
        myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);

}
```

I want to delete the old database that I was using and just have the new database available to the app layout.

Here is my LogCat when adding `createDataBase()` to `onUpgrade()`

```
03-06 15:17:15.348: V/DB Exists(2150): db exists
03-06 15:17:15.388: V/Database Upgrade(2150): Database version is higher than previous.
03-06 15:17:15.398: D/AndroidRuntime(2150): Shutting down VM
03-06 15:17:15.398: W/dalvikvm(2150): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f6d648)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.productguide/com.example.productguide.PowersportsEquivalent}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:204)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.example.productguide.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:143)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.example.productguide.DataBaseHelper.onUpgrade(DataBaseHelper.java:248)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.example.productguide.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:136)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.example.productguide.PowersportsEquivalent.onCreate(PowersportsEquivalent.java:57)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-06 15:17:15.418: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Since you are deleting database onUpgrade(), you should call createDataBase()?

Comment: When possible use sql alter table statements.  We want to digitally preserve everything we can.  Take a look at this upgrade code.  I got 500 points in bounty on it.  It details the Adams Upgrade Method which I named for the blog I found it on.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082468/sqlitedatabase-error-unhelpful-log/21295349#21295349

Comment: @Prakash. I have updated my original post on what happens when I add createDataBase() in my onUpgrade(). Also for some reason when I app my version number, it does not work the first time. It only sees that I have a database due to a log I have. It works after the second upping of the version number and I can see that onUpgrade() is called because of a log you can clearly see in my logcat

Comment: @danny117. I am not sure what exactly you are showing me. Sorry

Comment: @LukeG224 sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While browsing through Google, I have found an answer to my problem.

By adding the code below to my `copyDataBase()`

```
SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

// Once the DB has been copied, set the new version
checkdb.setVersion(DATABASE_VERSION);
}
catch(SQLiteException e)
{
//database does’t exist yet.
}
```

AND having the below code within `onUpgrade()`

```
if (oldVersion < newVersion){
    Log.v("Test", "Within onUpgrade. Old is: " + oldVersion + " New is: " + newVersion);
    myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
    try {
        copyDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My database now upgrades to the database and deletes the previous on every change of the `DATABASE_VERSION` integer.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. In my case too the DB was copied from Assets, and hence its version was 0. Now I am updating its version after copying the DB from assets exactly as per your suggestion, due to this onUpgrade gets called consistently when the DB_VERSION is incremented in the class

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
```

This is caused by calling e.g. `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` from `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` callbacks. The callbacks are invoked as part database opening process, attempting to open it again at that point would be an error that would potentially lead to infinite recursion unless `SQLiteOpenHelper` detected that and threw this exception.

Further down the stacktrace:

```
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
 at com.example.productguide.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:143)
 at com.example.productguide.DataBaseHelper.onUpgrade(DataBaseHelper.java:248)
```

So `onUpgrade()` calls `createDataBase()` that calls `getReadableDatabase()`. The code you posted doesn't show that, it's likely some other version of it.

To get tried and tested helper to use with prepopulated databases, consider [jgilfelt/sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: I never updated my code with the onUpgrade code on StackOverflow, I just did it on my end and I posted the LogCat. I would like, if possible, not have to change my code in my app to use that Sqlite Asset Helper.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a simpler solution, just add this to your DB Helper class:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    super.setForcedUpgrade(newVersion);
    super.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

This will ignore any previous version existing and replace it with the one in your 'asset' folder.